# Invalid API version parameter. Supported values are [1, 2] in OpenStack Glance

Tags: openstack, openstack-glance

After I install the glance, When I execute the:

```
[root@ha-node1 ~]# glance image-create --name "cirros-0.3.4-x86_64" --file cirros-0.3.4-x86_64-disk.img --disk-format qcow2 --container-format bare --visibility public --progress
```

I get the below error:

```
Invalid API version parameter. Supported values are [1, 2]
```

And if I use the glance image-list will get this error too:

```
[root@ha-node1 ~]# glance image-list 
Invalid API version parameter. Supported values are [1, 2]
```

And in my `/root/admin-openrc`:

```
export OS_USER_DOMAIN_ID=default
export OS_PROJECT_DOMAIN_ID=default
export OS_USERNAME=admin
export OS_PROJECT_NAME=admin
export OS_PASSWORD=passw0rd
export OS_IDENTITY_API_VERSION=3
export OS_AUTH_URL=http://devops.taobao.com:35357/v3
export OS_IMAGE_API_VERSION=3
```

I set the OS_IMAGE_API_VERSION is 3, why I can not use the `API version 3 parameter`

Someone know why there is the error?

My OpenStack is Newton. VM is CentOS 7.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Glance doesn't have a v3 API. The current API version is 2.5, and Newton supports 2.4. See [Image Service Versions](https://developer.openstack.org/api-ref/image/versions/index.html#api-versions) for additional details.